# CSS Style not being applied in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have the following html added statically the CSS style is applied correctly

**HTML:**

```
<li class="connector">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="css/images/temp/connector2.png" alt="" width="192" height="192">
      <span class="sr-only">box</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

However if I do the following in Javascript to dynamically render the HTML the CSS does not seem to get applied.

**JavaScript:**

```
element.innerHTML += "<li class='connector'>" +
                        "<a href = '/connector/" + i + "'>" +
                           "<img src ='/" + i + "/background' />" +
                           "<span class='sr-only'>" + $.get("/" + i + "/getName") +"</span>" +
                        "</a>" +
                     "</li>";
```

The list shows, but without the CSS styling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this CSS styling you keep talking about ?

Comment: What does the element look like in your browser's DOM inspector?

Comment: You should invert your use of `"` and `'`

Comment: @Brian, no, any of them are ok.

Comment: Seems to work fine : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/p8ARq/615/

Comment: @Blazemonger the elements in the DOM inspector appear to have positioning attributes that are not included in the Javascript generated elements.  However, the class specified in the Javascript is being applied.

Comment: @adeneo The CSS styling is in a file loaded in the header of the HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with how I was using the Isotope Javascript library.  The way I was adding the content was bypassing it.

After reading their documentation, I was able to get it to work properly.

I used the following instead

```
$.get("/connectorCount", function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data; i++)
    {
        var $newItems = $('<li class="connector"><a href = "/connector' + i + '"> <img src = "/' + i + '/background" /> <span class="sr-only">' + $.get("/" + i + "/getName") + '</span></a></li>');
        $('.connectors').isotope('insert', $newItems);
    }
    refreshSearch(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> "<span class='sr-only'>" + $.get("/" + i + "/getName") +"</span>" +
> ```

`get` is asynchronous method. This addition is wrong.

Comment: That would only impact the value, not the element to which class is associated

Comment: @DinoMyte, don't you think that response contains html markup?

Comment: The response would only have the underlying value, the markup is already being created and since $.get is an async, it would not impact the rendering of the dynamic element.